# Conditional Field Update Apex Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, field-update

Here's the situation:

We purchased software that pushes advertising clicks to a custom field called "Adroll Clicks", however the vendor does this on a company level, but not an individual level. Therefore, the pushback to the Lead object is flawed because it is only pushing "Adroll Clicks" to one lead where "company" = the company targeted by the ads. How can I create a trigger that does the following (please forgive the horrible attempt at my hybrid coding/English):

```
trigger update_adroll_fields on Lead (after insert, before update) {
  Map<String, Id> typeMap = New Map<ID,Adroll_clicks__c>();
  for(Adroll_clicks__c act: [Select ID, Adroll_clicks__c  Where sObjectType = 'update_adroll_fields']) {    
typeMap.put(act.Adroll_clicks__c, act.id);
    for (update_adroll_fields uaf: trigger.new)
  {
      // If the Lead 'company' = another Lead 'company'
      if (uaf.Adroll_clicks__c.company == 'company')
      {
          {
              // Then automatically change Adroll clicks where company = company
              uaf.Adroll_clicks__c = typeMap.get('Adroll_clicks__c');
           }
      }          
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to map the `Adroll_Clicks__c` object by company? Does it have a company field?

Comment: I believe the `'company'` in condition should be a dynamic value Or it should be coming from a pre-defined list.

Comment: Im trying to map Adroll_Clicks__c on the Lead object conditionally if the field 'company' (default field on Lead object) is an exact match. IE. If Adroll_Clicks__c not equal to null/blank, then push Adroll_Clicks__c to all leads that have the same 'company' field value. Hopefully thats a bit more helpful and I'm well aware that my code snippet is likely in the wrong galaxy. Thanks guys @AdrianLarson

Comment: You didn't really answer my question. Is there a `Company__c` field of some sort on the `Adroll_Clicks__c object? Is that what's supposed to be an exact match?

Comment: No. Both are on the Lead object. Adroll_Clicks__c is a custom field on Lead object and 'company' is a standard field on the Lead object

Comment: Did that help @AdrianLarson?

Comment: No, it's still very unclear. Try to [edit] your post to be as specific as you possibly can about the criteria you wish to apply, and about the action you wish to take. For example, *when a record on `Object_X__c` has `Field_Y__c = 'Value Z'`, set `Field_A__c = 'Value B'`*. Or the action might be more like *find `Object_O__c` record where `Field_P__c = 'Value Z'`*. As it is, this question is too loosely defined to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're first going to need to be able to find the Adroll_clicks__c that relate to the lead Id. I suspect there may not be a relationship between the Lead Id on the object, but instead the Lead's First and Last Name. If that's the case, you'll need to collect all of those into a map and then create your query to return your information in a form you can use to update your lead data. If there is an ID field for lead on Addroll_clicks, then your query will be much simpler.

If the only thing that's returned is the "company", unless that information is already populated in the Lead originally and there's a one to one relationship, between company and lead, it's going to get a bit more complicated in that you could have a one to many relationship between company and lead ID which sounds like the case based on your answer to comments.

**Edit**

Based on your latest comments, I understand Adroll_clicks__c to be a custom field on Lead. That simplifies your trigger vastly and you can ignore much of the original answer I began to write above which assumed Adroll clicks was a custom object.

Here's what I'd expect you'd need to do:

```
trigger update_adroll_fields on Lead (after insert, after update) {
  list<lead>leadsToUpdate = new list<lead>();

  If(!TriggerHelper.reEntry == true){
     //set boolean to true so won't run a 2nd time
     TriggerHelper.reEntry = true; 

     for(lead l:trigger.new){
        if(l.company.toUpperCase().normalizedSpace() != l.addroll_clicks__c.toUpperCase().normalizedSpace()){
           l.company = l.addroll_clicks__c;      
           leadsToUpdate.add(l);  
         }
     } 

     update leadsToUpdate;
  }   

}
```

I don't think it wise to make this a before update and have changed your trigger to make it an after insert and an after update

Use the class below to provide recursion protection so your trigger will only run once.

```
public with sharing class TriggerHelper {

   public static boolean reEntry = false; 

}
```

Comment: thanks so much! you nailed it on the head. Only one more thing I'd like to clarify. Is this checking that the leads belong exactly to the same company, before updating addroll_clicks__c?

Comment: It doesn't update `addroll_clicks__c`, instead it updates the `company` field on lead. it is checking to see that strings in the two fields are a match. Ideally, you'd also want to strip away any leading and trailing whitespace before making the check using `normalizeSpace()` and also apply `toUpperCase()` to both the company and the `addroll_clicks__c` during the comparison test.  That way none of those things affect your test. You can easily reverse the logic if you need to update `addroll_clicks__c`.

Comment: N.B. although the way the trigger is written avoids recursion, a recursion guard would be a good idea - or at least a comment in the code to that effect for the next poor sysad who inadvertently adds functionality to this trigger for some other use case

Comment: not really IMHO - because you are updating the Lead object in an after trigger that will re-invoke the same trigger again. @sfdcfox slapped my hands on this point in some past answer of mine :-)